# How much funds do I need in my bank account for 1 week in Ireland

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, ireland, entry-permit

I am planning a trip to Ireland, and I am from a country that does not require a visa.

My trip duration will be 6 to 7 days.
My partner will be paying for most of the trip, but they are also a tourist in Ireland (from the US). However, we will not be entering the country with the same flight.

If I have the plane ticket and accommodation already paid for, how much money will I need to prove to immigration that I have enough funds to not become a burden on the state

Comment: Be careful. You should avoid doing anything that looks like [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105).

Answer (score 1):

There is no set amount. Although you are a non-visa national, in order to satisfy any questions from Immigration officials on your arrival, you can still use the same documents a visa applicant would need to provide. This would include having with you, for example:

- an itinerary
- proof of accommodation
- bank statements

https://www.irishimmigration.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Required-documents-Short-Stay-C-Visa.-faq.pdf

Since you’re relying on your partner for most of the expenses, you should get a letter from them confirming how much the trip is expected to cost and how much they are contributing. It may also be best to book a flight that arrives *after* your partner’s flight. That way you can either meet up and clear Immigration together, or he/she will already have cleared border control and will be contactable landside if needed.

Comment: more specifically: https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/entry-for-non-eu-non-eea-and-non-swiss-nationals/#what